# How can I use boolean parameters from application.properties in spring security context configuration xml file?

Tags: spring, web-applications, spring-mvc, spring-security, application-server

I am trying to use a `boolean` parameter from my `application.properties` in my `spring-security configuration xml` file. 
I don't know why I can use not-boolean parameters, but I get an error for boolean.

How can I use boolean parameters?

Here is my application.properties:

```
JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema?user=username&password=password
protocol=http
USE_SECURE=false
```

My spring-security.xml is:

```
< remember-me user-service-ref="internalUserDetails" data-source-ref="dataSource" key="this-is-my-key02203452416fw" use-secure-cookie="${USE_SECURE}" />
```

...
but I get this error:
cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '${USE_SECURE}' is not a valid value for 'boolean'

I have also tried to set `USE_SECURE=False` but I get the same error again.
How can I use boolean parameters in the spring security configuration xml file?

Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0" >

    <display-name> Name-MyApp</display-name> 

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Servlets Mappings -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>MyApp</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>    

    <filter> 
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter> 

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Do you have a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` confifured?

Comment: I don't think that I need a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, the other properties in the same file work well, how can a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` help me for boolean values?

Comment: how r u loading the `application.properties` file to spring?

Comment: @ArunPJohny  `<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
  <property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties" />
</bean>` the other values in the properties file are loaded well,  probably @zagyi is right, later I will check it out

Comment: is it a web application and in which file you defined the `PropertyPlaceholderConfig‌` bean?

Comment: yes it is, the code above is in my servlet context definition xml file  , while the definition of my security context is in another xml file. Both are referred in my web.xml:  `<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
          /WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml,
   /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>` but basically the problem is when I try to load the paramater ${protocol} in the security context it works well

Comment: can you share the web.xml file?

Comment: Can you edit the question instead of adding it in comments

Comment: You can edit the question instead of adding the code in comments

Comment: There is an `edit` link at the end of the question (just before the comments starts)

Comment: yes, it was a bit painful but I got that ;)

Comment: this looks fine, are you able to use `${protocol}` in the security context file

Comment: yes, I am. It is exactly the point

Comment: Can you create a custom class with a `String` field to which you can assign the value `${USE_SECURE}`. It is a dump debugging step to see the value

Comment: Also it will be good if you can enable `debug/trace` level logging for the class `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfig‌​urer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xsd schema definition of the security namespace only allows boolean values in the `use-secure-cookie` attribute. If you don't specify one of the allowed literals ("true" or "false"), your xml won't pass the schema validation, and won't get even parsed.

So if you use the security namespace configuration, you won't be able to use external properties to set this value. To prove my point, here is the relevant code snippet from `RememberMeBeanDefinitionParser.parse()`:

```
String useSecureCookie = element.getAttribute("use-secure-cookie");
if (StringUtils.hasText(useSecureCookie)) {
    services.getPropertyValues().addPropertyValue(
                    "useSecureCookie", Boolean.valueOf(useSecureCookie));
}
```

As you can see the attribute is straight away converted to boolean, so no mechanism is given any chance to further process the value.

I'm not completely sure, but chances are that this could be fixed by simply relaxing the xsd to allow any string value, and pass that value to the bean definition (`services` above) without converting it to boolean. Then a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` could later resolve the given value if it happens to be a property placeholder.

If you want to give it a try, feel free to open a ticket in the [Spring Security issue tracker](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC).

Answer (score 3):

Looks that instead the value the key '${USE_SECURE}' is being passed. I come across similiar issue when I wanted to inistiate Boolean

```
<bean id="flag" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <constructor-arg value="${FLAG}"/>
</bean>
```

It works ok with the 'property', so i solved my case in other way. I am not sure if it is a spring bug?

Comment: and how do I set `use-secure-cookie` value? like this `use-secure-cookie=flag`?

Comment: I think Spring is smart enough to know that if a setter requires a boolean, and you type in "true", it converts it using the appropriate PropertyEditor.  At least that has been my experience in the past.

Comment: @CodeChimp, have I written `use-secure-cookie=flag` or `use-secure-cookie="true"` above?  I have a short memory <br> writing `use-secure-cookie="true"` is exactly what I want to avoid, read the post above please

Comment: First of all, there is not nead to get nasty in your response.  You are creating property, Yes?  You are setting that property value to either "true" or "false", Yes?  Then, in my experience, Spring will use the PropertyEditor to convert that to the Boolean type the setter expects.  Thats why that framework exists.  Does it matter that the value came from EL?  I wouldn't think so.  I would think that the Spring people, being the smart chaps they seem to be, had thought that if you allow someone to use EL to pull property values, that they would still use the same PropertyEditor mechinism.

Comment: Further more, if my assumption of "I am trying to use a boolean parameter from my application.properties..." is incorrect, and you ARE setting it to something other than "true" or "false", then write a custom PropertyEditor that handles the value you are expecting.  Again, that's why they have that mechinism in place was that they saw the need to injects complex types based on text inputs.